# Why do I get this error while trying to install rpy2 on Mac OSX Sierra?

Tags: rpy2

Trying to install rpy2 on Mac Sierra by entering

```
sudo pip install rpy2
```

on the command line.  Getting this error:

```
The directory '/Users/hodor/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

The directory '/Users/hodor/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting rpy2
  Downloading rpy2-2.8.5.tar.gz (184kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 184kB 27kB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (from rpy2)
Requirement already satisfied: singledispatch in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from rpy2)
Installing collected packages: rpy2
  Running setup.py install for rpy2 ... error
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-build-0H8VbG/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-umxGfs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --ldflags
    /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R CMD config --cppflags

```
    Compilation parameters for rpy2's C components:
        include_dirs    = ['/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include']
        library_dirs    = ['/usr/local/lib']
        libraries       = ['pcre', 'lzma', 'bz2', 'z', 'icucore', 'm', 'iconv']
        extra_link_args = ['-fopenmp', '-F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..', '-framework', 'R']

running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2
copying ./rpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2
copying ./rpy/rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2
copying ./rpy/tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2
copying ./rpy/tests_rpy_classic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
copying ./rpy/rlike/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
copying ./rpy/rlike/container.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
copying ./rpy/rlike/functional.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
copying ./rpy/rlike/indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_container.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_functional.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
copying ./rpy/rlike/tests/test_indexing.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rlike/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface
copying ./rpy/rinterface/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Device.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_EmbeddedR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_Sexp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpClosure.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpEnvironment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpExtPtr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpSymbol.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
copying ./rpy/rinterface/tests/test_SexpVectorNumeric.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/constants.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/conversion.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/environments.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/functions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/help.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/language.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/methods.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/numpy2ri.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/packages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/packages_utils.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/pandas2ri.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/robject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
copying ./rpy/robjects/vectors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testArray.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testDataFrame.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testEnvironment.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFormula.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testFunction.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testHelp.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testLanguage.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testMethods.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testNumpyConversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPackages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testPandasConversions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRObject.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testRobjects.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/tests/testVector.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/dplyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/ggplot2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grdevices.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/grid.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tidyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_dplyr.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_ggplot2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
copying ./rpy/robjects/lib/tests/test_grdevices.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/robjects/lib/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
copying ./rpy/interactive/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
copying ./rpy/interactive/packages.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
copying ./rpy/interactive/process_revents.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive/tests
copying ./rpy/interactive/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/interactive/tests
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython
copying ./rpy/ipython/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython
copying ./rpy/ipython/ggplot.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython
copying ./rpy/ipython/html.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython
copying ./rpy/ipython/rmagic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython
creating build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython/tests
copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython/tests
copying ./rpy/ipython/tests/test_rmagic.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/ipython/tests
running build_clib
building 'r_utils' library
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy
creating build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy/rinterface
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -c ./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ExternallyManagedVector *extvector = malloc(sizeof(ExternallyManagedVector));
                                       ^
./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
1 warning generated.
./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc' with type 'void *(unsigned long)' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  ExternallyManagedVector *extvector = malloc(sizeof(ExternallyManagedVector));
                                       ^
./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.c:230:40: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'malloc'
1 warning generated.
ar rc build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/libr_utils.a build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/r_utils.o
ranlib build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/libr_utils.a
running build_ext
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) -- "You Stupid Darkness"
building 'rpy2.rinterface._rinterface' extension
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -pipe -DR_INTERFACE_PTRS=1 -DHAVE_POSIX_SIGJMP=1 -DRIF_HAS_RSIGHAND=1 -DCSTACK_DEFNS=1 -DHAS_READLINE=1 -I./rpy/rinterface -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:98:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                          ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                          ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
      SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
           ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
  PyObject *copy = Py_True;
            ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:267:30: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'R_len_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    R_len_t slice_len = ihigh-ilow;
            ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~^~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:522:30: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long' to 'R_len_t' (aka 'int') [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
    R_len_t slice_len = ihigh-ilow;
            ~~~~~~~~~   ~~~~~^~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:347:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:373:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  if (consolecallback == NULL) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
  void *consolecallback;
                       ^
                        = NULL
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:582:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  int l=strlen(input_str);
      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:789:9: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  int l=strlen(path_str);
      ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1295:28: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'const Py_ssize_t' (aka 'const long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  status = Rf_initialize_R(n_args, options);
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:1694:13: warning: implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'Py_ssize_t' (aka 'long') to 'int' [-Wshorten-64-to-32]
  nparams = PySequence_Length(params);
          ~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/abstract.h:1065:27: note: expanded from macro 'PySequence_Length'
#define PySequence_Length PySequence_Size
                          ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
  static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                           ^
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
  static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                     ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2168:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
^
16 warnings generated.
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:8:
In file included from /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/R.h:81:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/Rconfig.h:20:9: warning: 'SIZEOF_SIZE_T' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define SIZEOF_SIZE_T 8
        ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/pymacconfig.h:56:17: note: previous definition is here
#        define SIZEOF_SIZE_T           4
                ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:98:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:6:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED;
                          ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.h:7:27: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
extern const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY;
                          ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:116:
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:5:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_INITIALIZED = 0x01;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:6:20: warning: duplicate 'const' declaration specifier [-Wduplicate-decl-specifier]
const unsigned int const RPY_R_BUSY = 0x02;
                   ^
./rpy/rinterface/embeddedr.c:48:12: warning: unused variable 'res' [-Wunused-variable]
      SEXP res = rpy2_remove(Rf_mkString(name_buf),
           ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:119:
./rpy/rinterface/sexp.c:742:13: warning: unused variable 'copy' [-Wunused-variable]
  PyObject *copy = Py_True;
            ^
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:347:3: warning: variable 'consolecallback' is used uninitialized whenever switch default is taken [-Wsometimes-uninitialized]
  default:
  ^~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:373:7: note: uninitialized use occurs here
  if (consolecallback == NULL) {
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:339:24: note: initialize the variable 'consolecallback' to silence this warning
  void *consolecallback;
                       ^
                        = NULL
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:52:
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:203:44: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_IsInitialized' [-Wunused-function]
  static PyRinterface_IsInitialized_RETURN PyRinterface_IsInitialized PyRinterface_IsInitialized_PROTO;
                                           ^
./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.h:204:38: warning: unused function 'PyRinterface_FindFun' [-Wunused-function]
  static PyRinterface_FindFun_RETURN PyRinterface_FindFun PyRinterface_FindFun_PROTO;
                                     ^
In file included from ./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.c:122:
./rpy/rinterface/sequence.c:2168:1: warning: unused function 'ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp' [-Wunused-function]
ComplexVectorSexp_AsSexp(PyObject *pyfloat) {
^
11 warnings generated.
cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -Wl,-F. build/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/./rpy/rinterface/_rinterface.o -L/usr/local/lib -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7 -L/usr/local/lib -lpcre -llzma -lbz2 -lz -licucore -lm -liconv -lr_utils -o build/lib.macosx-10.12-intel-2.7/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so -fopenmp -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/tmp/pip-build-0H8VbG/rpy2/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-umxGfs-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-0H8VbG/rpy2/

Answer (score 1):

In trying to solve a similar issue, I came across [this problem thread](https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/403/cannot-pip-install-rpy2-with-latest-r-340) on the RPy2 Bitbucket. Apparently the latest R (3.4.0 "Single Candle") was built using the `-fopenmp` flag from Clang 4.0.0, which is now not supplied by Apple. If you can use R 3.3.3, then that could serve as a workaround. Alternatively, you could try modifying `setup.py` to remove the `-fopenmp` flag by adding the following after line 272:

```
if "-fopenmp" in unknown:
    unknown.remove("-fopenmp")
```

If neither work, you can always force brew to use gcc to install it with the command:

```
env CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/gcc-7 pip install rpy2
```

or if you try one of these solutions and get an error that looks like this:

```
ld: in '/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib', file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libunwind.dylib for architecture i386
clang-5.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

you can try installing using the command:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" pip install rpy2
```

to ensure the architecture is correct. Or combine them:

```
env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" CC=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/gcc-7 pip install rpy2
```

Really, this seems to be a bit of a Frankenstein issue. Different solutions worked for different people - the above were the most common ones. It's not something that is likely to have an easy fix soon, either, since it seems to be an issue on R's end.